# PDFKit - How to click to jump to a page with pdfkit for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I have a list of link in a page in my pdf document generated by pdfkit for nodejs like:

- Click to go to page 1
- Click to go to page 2
- ....
- Click to go to page n

Does the current version of PDFkit support this, I've searched but just found it work on some external link only:

```
doc.text('Go to page 1', x, y, {
    link: 'page1'
}
```